# building a area plot in R

Tags: r, ggplot2

I´m trying to build a graph that plots relative abundance against depth variation.

I have the following table

```
          test X1m X2m X3m X4m X5m X6m X7m
1 Example1   1  10  10   1   1   5   1
2 Example2   2   5   5   5   2   2   5
```

and I have tried the following using ggplot2()

```
 Example.class.melt<-melt(Example.df)
colnames(Example.class.melt)[1] = "Class"
colnames(Example.class.melt)[2] = "Depth"
colnames(Example.class.melt)[3] = "Relative_abundance"

Example.class.melt<-as.data.frame(Example.class.melt)

ggplot(Example.class.melt, aes(x=Depth, y=Relative_abundance, fill=as.factor(Class))) + geom_area()
```

For some reason, that I don´t understand, it isn´t working. Any suggestion to correct this or any alternative?

thanks

Comment: I think "Depth" should be a number instead of a factor.  Based on the numbers in your example this may be a rare case where `as.numeric(Depth)` would work, although that can be dangerous.  You could also pull out the numbers and make a new variable using something like `as.numeric(gsub("[[:alpha:]]", "", Example.class.melt$Depth))`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]Is this what you are looking for?This was my interpretation based on the way you asked the question. The code is as follows:

```
install.packages("ggplot2")
install.packages("reshape")
library(ggplot2)
library(reshape)

Example1<-c(1,10,10,1,1,5,1)
Example2<-c(2,5,5,5,2,2,5)
data<-rbind(Example1,Example2)

Example.class.melt<-melt(data)
colnames(Example.class.melt)[1] = "Class"
colnames(Example.class.melt)[2] = "Depth"
colnames(Example.class.melt)[3] = "Relative_abundance"

Example.class.melt<-as.data.frame(Example.class.melt)

ggplot(data = Example.class.melt, aes(x = Depth, y = Relative_abundance, fill=Class)) + geom_area()
```

You don't require to say `as.factor` in fill to class.